# jQuery animate an object when object clicked and when body is clicked, animate again

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, click

Hi i have this simple jQuery code:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.menu-icon').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 200);
    });
    $('body').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: '-200px'
        }, 200);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

I want to make a menu appear when .menu-icon is clicked and disappear when everything except .menu and .menu-icon is clicked. What happens is that both animations occur when i press .menu-icon. I also would like to have an special page for each item in the list below, and when pressed on the menu it loads that page.

I have this list:

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="home">Home</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="apps">Apps</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="themes">Themes</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="request">Requests/Fixes</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="help">Help</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="about">About</div></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `.menu-icon` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A click bubbles, so when you click `.menu-icon` the click also propagates to the body, firing both event handlers.

You could do this with a single event handler instead

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        var left = '-200px';

        if ( $(e.target).closest('.menu-icon').length ) {
            left = '0px';
        }

        $('.menu').animate({
            left: left
        }, 200);

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to make body blur also when menu is shown, i've tried using blurjs but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Register the body handler as a `one` event, meaning it will only run once. Then declare that after you have clicked the element:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.menu-icon').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 200);

        // Bind once here
        $('body').one('click',  function() {
            $('.menu').animate({
                left: '-200px'
            }, 200);
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

This way the event-handler only exists, while the `.menu` is showing. Tada!